# Merged Static Contents

Tags: magento2.3.4, cdn

Is it possible to generate merged static contents programmatically in magento2? There is issue with sync merged static contents in CDN, multi-server setup with load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Magento can minify and merge CSS and JS files.

This is automatically done in production mode.

Make sure the following settings are set to 1 in the table core_config_data

- dev/js/merge_files
- dev/js/minify_files
- dev/css/merge_files
- dev/css/minify_files